# How to check Shipment lines before confirming?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to cycle though the SOShipLines before confirming to validate the data.  I've got the override to work, but can't seem to figure out how I move through the records. The error (which is set to always trip) always returns 0 lines. I'm pretty sure I need to be looking at the `shiporder` variable but don't know how.

```cs
    public void ConfirmShipment(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder, ConfirmShipmentDelegate baseMethod)
    {

      int TheCount = 0;
      int TheLines = 0;

    string TheTest = "";

      SOShipLineExt TheSOLineExt = null;

        foreach (SOShipLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
          {

            TheLines += 1;

            TheSOLineExt = PXCache<SOShipLine>.GetExtension<SOShipLineExt>(line);

            TheTest += "-" + TheSOLineExt.UsrSpeedyShippedPieces;

            if (TheSOLineExt.UsrSpeedyShippedPieces==null)
            {

              TheCount += 1;

            }

              //UpdateLineDirect(Base.Caches[typeof(SOLine)], line);
          };
      //}; if (TheCount > 0 )
      throw new PXException("What the hell!!!" + Convert.ToString(TheCount) + "/" + Convert.ToString(TheLines));

      baseMethod(docgraph,shiporder);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

-Travis

Comment: Looking at TheSOLineExt.UsrSpeedyShippedPieces==null -> Are you sure the value would be null and not 0?  Maybe try if(TheSOLineExt.UsrSpeedyShippedPieces == null || TheSOLineExt.UsrSpeedyShippedPieces == 0) {} and see if that catches your condition.  Also, if you aren't using Debug in Visual Studio to monitor your the foreach loop, you could embed PXTrace.WriteInformation("You are here") in the foreach block to make sure it actually retrieves records as you expect.  Since the PXException is after the foreach block, it will fire even if you don't find any SOShipLine records.

Comment: As Brian Stevens said it should be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in an undefined current `SOShipment` record. Please look at `Base.Transactions` view - there is `Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>` definition there

```
public PXSelect<SOShipLine, 
    Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>, 
    OrderBy<Asc<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Asc<SOShipLine.sortOrder>>>> Transactions;
```

Then look at base `ConfirmShipment` method and you will see special code which sets current record equal to your `SOShipment shiporder` parameter

```
this.Clear();
Document.Current = Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(shiporder.ShipmentNbr);
```

I suppose that the current `SOShipment` record is skipping somewhere before the `ConfirmShipment` method - this why `Base.Transactions.Select()` returns nothing

**There are 2 possible solutions from my standpoint:**

---

Set current `SOShipment` record equal to your `SOShipment shiporder` parameter as it is done inside the base `ConfirmShipment` method

```
Base.Clear() // maybe this is a good idea to call the Clear method too
Document.Current = Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(shiporder.ShipmentNbr);
```

---

**Or** write your own BQL select with a required parameter instead of current

```
foreach (SOShipLine line in PXSelect<SOShipLine,
    Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>,
    OrderBy<Asc<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Asc<SOShipLine.sortOrder>>>>
    .Select(Base, shiporder.ShipmentNbr))
{
    // do something here
}
```